# Big-O complexity of a piece of code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a question in algorithm design about complexity. In this question a piece of code is given and I should calculate this code's complexity. 
The pseudo-code is:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    j=i
    do{
        k=j;
        j = j / 2;
    }while(k is even);
}
```

I tried this algorithm for some numbers. and I have gotten different results. for example if n = 6 this algorithm output is like below

```
i = 1 -> executes 1 time
i = 2 -> executes 2 times
i = 3 -> executes 1 time
i = 4 -> executes 3 times
i = 5 -> executes 1 time
i = 6 -> executes 2 times
```

It doesn't have a regular theme, how should I calculate this?

Comment: worst case is O(n*log n)

Comment: what is your solution buddy ? @sp2danny

Comment: @sp2danny I disagree : worst case is `n`... See my answer or @interjay one's!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The upper bound given by the other answers is actually too high. This algorithm has a O(n) runtime, which is a tighter upper bound than O(n*logn).

Proof: Let's count how many total iterations the inner loop will perform.

The outer loop runs `n` times. The inner loop runs at least once for each of those.

- For even `i`, the inner loop runs at least twice. This happens `n/2` times.
- For `i` divisible by 4, the inner loop runs at least three times. This happens `n/4` times.
- For `i` divisible by 8, the inner loop runs at least four times. This happens `n/8` times.
- ...

So the total amount of times the inner loop runs is:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ... <= 2n
```

The total amount of inner loop iterations is between `n` and `2n`, i.e. it's Θ(n).

Comment: +1 Suprised to not see this as the accepted answer. While it's technically true that it is O(n log n), it's not really asymptotic... Also, here's a Θ if you want to edit it in

Comment: "The upper bound given by the other answers is actually too high." is false.  A better formulation is "... is actually higher than they need to be."

Answer (score 6):

You always assume you get the worst scenario in each level. 
now, you iterate over an array with N elements, so we start with `O(N)` already.
now let's say your `i` is always equals to `X` and `X` is always even (remember, worst case every time).
 how many times you need to divide `X` by `2` to get `1` ? (which is the only condition for even numbers to stop the division, when they reach 1).
in other words, we need to solve the equation 
`X/2^k = 1` which is `X=2^k` and `k=log<2>(X)`
this makes our algorithm take `O(n log<2>(X))` steps, which can easly be written as `O(nlog(n))`

Comment: I originally did the same analysis, but I think it is incomplete. While the outer loop is executed `n` times and the inner loop has worst-case complexity of O(log(n)), it does not follow that the overall complexity is O(n log(n)); it depends on how often the worst-case complexity of the inner loop occurs as `i` varies from 1 to `n`. My guess is that this frequency is not O(n) and that the overall complexity is actually lower (perhaps O(log(n)^2)).

Comment: again, the worst case is a compound calculation of all the worst cases the problem poses. you are talking about the average complexity, where *usually* the input does not pose worst case scenario each time.

Comment: The worst case here is O(n), as shown by my answer. (It's somewhat meaningless to talk about worst-case vs. average case though, because the algorithm doesn't have input other than `n` itself).

Comment: please demonstrate you answer on array with n elements, each with the value of 2^n.

Comment: But that's an unfair request. The array is specifically [1, 2, ..., n]. I don't think O(n log(n)) necessarily follows. To take an extreme example, suppose the inner loop had worst-case behavior of O(log(i)) for exactly one value of `i` and O(1) for all other values. Then the fact that the outer loop executes `n` times would not result in an overall complexity of O(n log(n)); it would be O(n) + O(log(n)) = O(n). The actual inner loop doesn't have this extreme behavior, of course, but it's far from clear (to me) that the density of worst-case behavior warrants the conclusion of O(n log(n)).

Comment: but we're talking about big O notation, which is the upper bound, you are correct that tight bound is not Theta(nlog(n)) , but O(nlog n) bind the complexity on the top.

Comment: By that logic, you could also say that the complexity is O(2^n) and be correct. I don't think that reasoning is in the spirit of the question.

Comment: @RobOcel: No, it's not a matter of worst vs. average.  The worst-case is still O(n) *(which technically means it's also O(n log n))*.   If n is odd it is still O(n) - you are enumerating all values from 1 to n, not just n itself.

Comment: If you want to lawyer, every algorithm is O(infinity) and Omega(1), but that doesn't actually mean anything.  Theta bounds are more interesting in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

For such loop, we cannot separate count of inner loop and outer loop -> variables are tighted!

We thus have to count all steps.

In fact, for each iteration of outer loop (on `i`), we will have

```
1 + v_2(i) steps
```

where `v_2` is the 2-adic valuation (see for example : http://planetmath.org/padicvaluation) which corresponds to the power of `2` in the decomposition in prime factor of `i`.

So if we add steps for all `i` we get a total number of steps of :

```
n_steps = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (1 + v_2(i)) 
        = n + v_2(n!)    // since v_2(i) + v_2(j) = v_2(i*j)
        = 2n - s_2(n)    // from Legendre formula (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula with `p = 2`)
```

We then see that the **number of steps** is ***exactly*** :

```
n_steps = 2n - s_2(n)
```

As `s_2(n)` is the sum of the digits of `n` in base `2`, it is negligible (at most `log_2(n)` since digit in base `2` is 0 or 1 and as there is at most `log_2(n)` digits) compared to `n`.

So the complexity of your algorithm is equivalent to `n`:

```
n_steps = O(n)
```

which is ***not*** the `O(nlog(n))` stated in many other solutions but a smaller quantity!

Comment: the example provided loops n times and then in it's worst case where i is even and is the result of 2^x 1 + log_2(i) iterations to become "odd" or more accurately `1 + Omega(n)` where `Omega(n)` returns the number of prime factors .e.g `6 = 2,3`, so it's not n +... but n logn. I think you missed the for loop on line 1?

Comment: @AlexanderHolman I disagree : as stated in this solution, the n_steps = 2*n - s_2(n) is an exact solution and a worst case for one iteration can be extended but this remains a worst estimation that an exact one... The sum for the loop over the i loop is indicated by the line : n_steps = \sum_{i=1}^n ...

Comment: Yep I was wrong! At this time of night I honestly can't work out if you are right... Your magic seems to work! +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

lets start with worst case:

if you keep dividing with 2 (integral) you don't need to stop until you 
get to 1. basically making the number of steps dependent on bit-width,
something you find out using two's logarithm. so the inner part is log n.
the outer part is obviously n, so `N log N` total.

Answer (score 0):

A `do` loop halves `j` until `k` becomes odd. `k` is initially a copy of `j` which is a copy of `i`, so `do` runs 1 + power of `2` which divides `i`:

- i=1 is odd, so it makes 1 pass through `do` loop,
- i=2 divides by 2 once, so 1+1,
- i=4 divides twice by 2, so 1+2, etc.

That makes at most 1+log(i) `do` executions (logarithm with base 2).

The `for` loop iterates `i` from 1 through `n`, so the upper bound is `n` times (1+log n), which is O(n log n).